# Delete a file on 'Cache Clear' in IE

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, winapi

We are creating a browser extension for IE. We are using the ATL and C++ to create the same.

we are writing a file: `AuthTest.txt` on successful login inside

```
%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explore
```

to store some information during the session. On logout, we are deleting the file as well.

My question is when a user clears the cache of IE browser, `AuthTest.txt` will not be deleted.
So how would I delete the file on cache clear from my code?

Answer (score 0):

IE maintains a database of the files that are in its cache. You have to tell IE about your file so it can be added to that database. Look at [`CreateUrlCacheEntry()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383968.aspx), [`CommitUrlCacheEntryA()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384269.aspx), and [`CommitUrlCacheEntryW()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384270.aspx).  Refer to MSDN for more details about working with the IE cache:

[Caching (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383928.aspx)

Comment: I tried the above examples you suggested, But none of those worked. Can you provide some sample implementation for the same, or any reference.

Comment: It would be better if you updated your question to show the code you have tried so far that is not working for you.